# Xcode 6 constraints not aligning view correctly

Tags: xcode, swift, constraints

Please forgive me, as I am new to Xcode and Swift.

I am working with a simple Login screen for an app, however the auto constraints are not working properly. When I use "Reset to suggested constraints" in the editor and run the app, I get an error message saying "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.", and a View containing text fields disappears from the middle of the view controller.

I found that if I remove the constraint from the center view to the submit button, I get no error message when building the project. However, the Login and center view are not properly centered as they should be, giving me this:

http://i724.photobucket.com/albums/ww243/caba8685/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-03%20at%202.25.37%20PM_zpsrnxudlii.png

Here is what the constraints on the center view look like:

http://i724.photobucket.com/albums/ww243/caba8685/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-03%20at%202.36.40%20PM_zpsahqanf4l.png

Does this possibly have to do with putting constraints on a view or background image?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they all supposed to be centered? If so, give everything a horizontal center constraint, then constrain their widths, heights, and top margin. No more.